# PrimeNG Tab Menu items not updating with model change

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a angular project using the PrimeNG TabMenu component.

`<p-tabMenu [model]="items"></p-tabMenu>`

The problem is when `items` is updated in the component there is no visual change to the tab menu. I would expect the tabs to be upated when the `items` change. This occurs if I try to add or remove tabs or if I update tab properties (ex: visibility).

I believe this was working in versions prior to PrimeNG 16. It appears that maybe they have changed the change detection to `onPush` and that is causing this.

I've tried using observables and signals to contain the menu items but changes to those still aren't reflected in the component. I have also run into this issue with other PrimeNG components.

Here is a StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hitagv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftab-menu-basic-demo.html

Comment: I actually took a better look at the PrimeNG tabMenu source and it's not the change detection that is causing the problem. On load it copies the array given in `model` to a new array and filters out the non-displayed items. Therefore when the menu array is updated there is no link to the menu items that are displayed and thus it's not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround is to toggle the visibilty of the component using `*ngIf`:

1-Define a boolean property in your `.ts`:

```
menuChanged:boolean = true;
```

2- add the `*ngIf="menuChanged"` on  `p-tabMenu` component:

```
  <p-tabMenu
    #tabMenu
    [model]="items"
    *ngIf="menuChanged"
    styleClass="scalein"
  ></p-tabMenu>
```

Add `scalein` class to your compoenet in order to make it more smoother when hide and show

3- inside the function when you update the items set the `menuChanged` to `false` before update the items and after update the items change it back to `true`:

```
 updateMenuItems() {
    this.menuChanged = false;
    this.items = [
      { label: 'Home', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home' },
      { label: 'Calendar', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar' },
    ];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.menuChanged = true;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

> It's absolutely a workaround but it works